# Find where the $x$ and $y$ axis are mapped under the following complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be defined as $f(z)=\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}$.

Now, so far I know the function is analytic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$, so it's comformal in this set. However, I can't find a way to know where do the axis end up.

I tried dissecting the function for $z=u+iv$ into its Real and imaginary parts, but then I get this

$$\operatorname{Re}(f)=\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{(u-1)^2+v^2}$$

$$\operatorname{Im}(f)=\frac{-2v}{(u-1)^2+v^2}$$

What I'm trying to do is obtain the real part of $f$ as a function of the imaginary part of $f$. But my attempts were useless.

Let $z=t+0i$, now that would imply:

$$\operatorname{Re}(f)=\frac{t+1}{t-1}$$

$$\operatorname{Im}(f)=0$$

Now, let $z=0+ti$. That would imply:

$$\operatorname{Re}(f)=\frac{t^2-1}{1+t^2}$$

$$\operatorname{Im}(f)=\frac{-2t}{1+t^2}$$

By combining the real and imaginary parts of this image, I obtain a function of $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ and $t$. I'd like to see the function is conformal, how can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Moebius tranformations send lines to either lines or circles, this might be useful to know.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  Shouldn't z=x+iy?

Comment: If you get the image of $u+iv$ under f you get $Re(f)+iIm(f)$ with Re and Im defined in my post

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Johnny Lemmon, Moebius transforms send lines to lines and circles to circles.

The image of imaginary axis is not a line, so we suppose it's a circle on the complex plane. simple verification will find that
$$
|f|^2=\operatorname{Re}(f)^2+\operatorname{Im}(f)^2\\
=(\frac{t^2-1}{1+t^2})^2+(\frac{-2t}{1+t^2})^2\\
=\frac{(t^2-1)^2+4t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}
=1
$$
So the image of imaginary axis is the unit circle.

Under the map $(0,0)\mapsto(-1,0)$ and indeed, the unit circle and real axis are perpendicular at $(-1,0)$ just like real axis and imaginary axis are perpendicular at $(0,0)$. This is in consistent with the conformal mapping.

---

Actually if you let $t=\tan\theta/2$ then we have $z=0+it\mapsto f(z)=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta=e^{-i\theta}$